# Bootstrap collapsable table suggestions

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have a table that has a lot of columns. I am trying to represent information that can be collapsed. Basically rows/columns that can be collapsed.

I have already tried Bootstrap accordion, but cannot get it working with datatables, so that is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with databases, why don't you call just these columns the users need?

My Idea is, that they could select some boxes or search or whatever and then the data gets filtered.